# Haproxy Bad Gateway 502

Tags: java, servlets, nginx, jetty, haproxy

So I am using HAProxy in front of Jetty servlets.
The goal at the moment is just proof of concept and load and stress testing once everything's configured.
However I have a problem configuring haproxy. I know that it's not a problem with my application cause I have nginx(tengine) running and everything works properly. So it has to be something with the haproxy configuration or just the way haproxy works is not suitable for my needs.

So what my client tries to do is connect to haproxy using two different connections and keep them open:

1. Connect with a chunked streaming mode for upload.
2. Connect with a normal mode and establish a download channel.

Here's how my haproxy.conf file looks like:

```
global
log /dev/log    local0
log /dev/log    local1 notice
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
stats timeout 30s
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon

# Default SSL material locations
# ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
# crt-base /etc/ssl/private

# Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
# For more information, see ciphers(1SSL).
ssl-default-bind-ciphers kEECDH+aRSA+AES:kRSA+AES:+AES256:RC4-SHA:!kEDH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL
maxconn 2048

defaults
log global
mode    http
option forwardfor
option http-server-close
option  httplog
option  dontlognull
timeout connect 5000
timeout client  50000
timeout server  50000
errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
stats enable
stats uri /stats
stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
stats auth user:password

frontend www-http
   bind *:80
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
   default_backend www-backend

frontend www-https
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/server.pem
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
   default_backend www-backend

backend www-backend
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    server www-1 localhost:8080 check maxconn 2048
```

And here's what my logs say when I try to access port 443:

> Sep 17 11:10:18 xxxxx-pc haproxy[15993]: 127.0.0.1:32875 [17/Sep/2014:11:10:18.464] www-  https~ www-backend/www-1 0/0/0/-1/1 502 212 - - PH-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /test HTTP/1.1"

Any ideas what the problem might be?
An issue with the configuration or ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PH means that haproxy rejected the header from the backend because it was malformed.
http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt

> PH -    The proxy blocked the server's response, because it was invalid,
>             incomplete, dangerous (cache control), or matched a security filter.
>             In any case, an HTTP 502 error is sent to the client. One possible
>             cause for this error is an invalid syntax in an HTTP header name
>             containing unauthorized characters. It is also possible but quite
>             rare, that the proxy blocked a chunked-encoding request from the
>             client due to an invalid syntax, before the server responded. In this
>             case, an HTTP 400 error is sent to the client and reported in the
>             logs.